# How to disable automatic updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

How can I disable automatic updates in Windows 10? I would prefer to install updates as and when I choose. This was an option in Windows 7 but looks to be missing in Windows 10.

Needless to say 'unplug the internet' isn't a satisfactory solution.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/224471/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-downloading-updates/

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/turn-off-automatic-updating-in-windows

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8013-windows-update-automatic-updates-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Hit the windows key+R and type in services.msc and hit enter. From there scroll down to "Windows Update" and stop the service. I would however advise against doing this as keeping an up to date system is very important for security reasons